# How to insert value in a IEnumerable<int>?

Tags: c#

I have this :

```
IEnumerable<int> intYear = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
```

how can I insert some values? I Don't see any intYear.Add() method.

Like 2010, 2011, and so on...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use an `IList<int>` instead of `IEnumerable<int>` for that:

```
IList<int> intYear = new List<int>();
intYear.Add(2011);
// and so on
```

`IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you can pass it to any method taking an `IEnumerable<T>` as argument.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use an `ICollection<T>`, as `IEnumerable<T>` is only used for iterating over collections.

```
ICollection<int> years = new List<T>();
years.Add(2010);
years.Add(2011);
```

Answer (score 3):

IEnumerable does not have an Add Method. You should use IList instead.

```
IList<int> intYear = new List<int>();
intYear.Add(2010);
```

Comment: The reSharper suggestion:  var intYear = new List<int> {2010};    I like your way more myself because I'll forget how to do it that way if I use the shortcuts all the time.

Answer (score 0):

By using [Concat(IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784338.aspx) method of IEnumerable Class you can first fill all the values to a List and then assign it to the IEnumerable list.

Comment: If you could make that work, it would not be simple. There are simpler ways.

Comment: @DonkeyMaster, is there any thing wrong in my post? if wrong then you can downvote it right?

Comment: The `IEnumerable<T>` interface doesn't specify a `Concat` method. There's an extension method, but it returns a new, third object. That behavior will probably surprise the OP. Interpreting the original post, it seems that what the OP needs is an `IList<T>`.